# Ajuda com SQL para somar diárias entre datas

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho duas tabelas: empresa e caminhao

Na tabela caminhao, tenho os campos dataentrada, datasaida, valordiaria
Gostaria de selecionar todas as empresas, e listar ela e o valor total que a empresa gastou em diárias, somente se a datasaida for diferente de '0000-00-00 00:00:00' no caso. Se não completou a diária, tipo 1 dia e 20 horas por exemplo, a diária é contada igual. Sempre arredondado pra cima.

Estou utilizando PHP.
Estou empacado nesse SQL que precisa primeiro descobrir quantas diárias deu no total para cada caminhão, daí depois fazer vezes o valor da diária, e depois somar todos os totais e gerar o total que foi gasto por cada empresa.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM empresa WHERE emp_ativo = '1' ORDER BY emp_nome ASC");
while ($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){

    $sql_valor = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM caminhao WHERE cam_ativo = '1' AND emp_id = '".$linha['emp_id']."' AND cam_datasaida != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'");
    while ($val = mysql_fetch_array($sql_valor)){
        ...
    }

    $lista[] = $linha;

}
```

Comment: post os modelos das tabelas, de preferencia no [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) para poder construir a query

Comment: Eu faria uma Function , que receberia data de entrada e data saida e calcularia a quantidade de dias (arredondando) o select seria mais simples select id,sum(qtd_dias(dataentrada,datasaida)) qtdduas from caminhao group by id , não publico como solução pois falta a function em si.

Comment: Seria melhor você passar os modelos como o Caputo disse, mas talvez o que você queira seja algo como:

SELECT e.emp_id, e.emp_nome, SUM(c.cam_valordiaria) AS total_diarias
FROM empresa e
JOIN caminhao c ON c.cam_ativo = '1' AND c.emp_id = e.emp_id AND AND e.cam_datasaida != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
WHERE e.emp_ativo = '1'
GROUP BY (e.emp_id)
ORDER BY e.emp_nome ASC

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função `DATEDIFF` do `mysql`. A sintaxe é a seguinte:

```
DATEDIFF(date1,date2)
```

Em uma query ficaria assim:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2015-07-24', '2014-07-24') AS DiffDate
```

O retorno é:

```
+----------+
| DiffDate |
+----------+
|      365 |
+----------+
```

Sendo 365 a diferença entre 24/07/2015 e 24/07/2014.

Se você precisar da diferença em horas, pode usar a função `TIMEDIFF`, cuja sintaxe é a mesma:

```
TIMEDIFF(expr1,expr2)
```

Em uma query ficaria assim:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('2014-07-28 12:45:00', '2014-07-24 10:55:00') AS DiffTime
```

O retorno é:

```
+----------+
| DiffTime |
+----------+
| 97:50:00 |
+----------+
```

Se você precisar da diferença em decimal, 1.5 horas por exemplo, podemos usar `TIMEDIFF` em conjunto com a função `TIME_TO_SEC`, cuja sintaxe é a seguinte:

```
TIME_TO_SEC(time)
```

Em uma query ficaria assim:

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('2014-07-24 16:48:00', '2014-07-24 07:00:00'))/3600 AS DecimalTime
```

O retorno é:

```
+-------------+
| DecimalTime |
+-------------+
|      9.8000 |
+-------------+
```

Espero ter ajudado :)

## Atualizando

---

Como você necessita do valor em dias, basta dividir o resultado obitido por 24, ficando da seguinte maneira:

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('2014-07-24 16:48:00', '2014-07-24 07:00:00'))/3600/24 AS DecimalTime
```

O retorno é:

```
+-----------------+
| DecimalTime     |
+-----------------+
|      0.40833333 |
+-----------------+
```